# Activating Venv in Bash without changing child directory

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ubuntu-16.04

Edit: Thanks to everyone commenting below. The purpose of this question was to figure out a way to execute the **venv** given that we are in a child directory and the **venv** folder is located in parent directory.

example: there are three folders inside parent directory:

**/home/iamuser/ ls**

**.venv    random_files      pictures**

Currently we are inside folder "random_files"**(/home/iamuser/random_files)** . We need to find out a way to start venv which is inside parent directory.

1. First way is to use cd .. to get to the parent directory**(/home/iamuser/)** , then type Source ./venv/bin/activate
2. Second way is to use the following command directly from "random_files" folder.

**Source ../venv/bin/activate**

This will start venv in "random_files" folder (child directory) without forcing us to change directories.

The issue is solved. I hope my answer helps someone.

*****************************OLD Thread *******************************

I have been trying how can I activate virtual environment without changing path.

While writing this question, I am at: /home/user

If I do cd .. I will go back one directory to the home, if I do cd .. again I will go back to the top of the tree.

At that place, I have my venv located.

To activate venv, I use cd.. twice to go to that position and then I type source venv/bin/activate. I am looking for a solution where I donot have to use cd.. twice

Can I get a script that could activate venv without forcing me to change directory.

Comment: This question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the absolute path 
`source /venv/bin/activate`

Comment: I will have to cd .. 2 times to use this command. I want to use the command inside /home/user

Comment: did you try it with this statement?
Otherwise `cd /` gets you there

Comment: By using cd, I will move to that directory, I donot want to change the directory, I want to launch a program (in this case it is venv) which is in another directory, without changing my location.